# Startup Applications config path

Tags: linux-mint, configuration, startup, cinnamon

I want to edit the startup list of Linux Mint 17 without logging in. Where does the **Startup Applications** program keep its list of applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily find the location of such configuration info by making a small change to one of the application settings (make sure you can undo it if necessary) and then do:

```
 find ~ -type f -mmin  -1
```

Which find all files under your home directory that changed in the last minute.

You will find that the files are under `~/.config/autostart/` (for each user)